$\frac{\text {d}y}{\text {d}x} = e^y$ general solution $y = -\ln(-x+C)$ or $y = -\ln|-x+C|$?
Is the general solution for $\frac{\text {d}y}{\text {d}x} = e^y$
$$y = -\ln(-x+C)$$
or
$$y = -\ln|-x+C|$$
or something else?
Here are the steps I'm taking:
$$\begin{align} \frac{\text {d}y}{\text {d}x} & = e^y & \text{0. start}\\ e^{-y}\text {d}y & = \text {d}x & \text{1. separate dependent} y \text{and independent } x \\ \int e^{-y}\text {d}y & = \int \text {d}x & \text{2. integrate both sides} \\-\int e^u \text {d}u & = \int \text {d}x & \text{3. substitute } u = -y, \text{ constant multiple rule}\\-e^u + C_1 & = \int \text {d}x & \text{4. exponential rule} \\-e^{-y} + C_1 & = \int \text {d}x & \text{5. undo substitution} \\ -e^{-y} + C_1 & = x + C_2 & \text{6. constant rule} \\ e^{-y} - C_1 & = -x - C_2 & \text{7. multiply both sides by} -1 \\ e^{-y} & = -x - C & \text{8. combine constants of integration} \\ \ln(e^{-y}) & = \ln(-x - C) & \text{9. take natural log of both sides} \\ -y & = \ln(-x - C) & \text{10. definition of natural log} \\ y & = -\ln(-x - C) & \text{11. multiply both sides by} -1 \end{align}$$
So I end up with
$$y = -\ln(-x+C)$$
but the given answer is
$$y = -\ln|-x+C|$$
with the absolute value bars. Have I gone wrong somewhere? Why would it be $y = -\ln|-x+C|$ with the absolute value bars?

Your answer is right and the given answer is wrong. One can check for example that $y=-\ln|{-}x|$ is not a solution to the differential equation when $x>0$ (where $y=-\ln x$).

I was also staring at it and wondering. Maybe they confused the necessity of $x \mapsto e^x$ being everywhere positive with the (right thing to do, which is) invoking the domain restriction given by $-x-C > 0$, i.e. $x < -C$.

Checking the given answer:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( -\ln |-x-C| \right)
    &= \frac{-1}{|-x-C|}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( |-x-C| \right)  \\
    &= \frac{-1}{|-x-C|} \cdot \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} |u| \right)_{u = -x-C} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(-x-C)  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\frac{-1}{|-x-C|} \cdot -1 \cdot -1 ,& -x-C < 0\\ 
\frac{-1}{|-x-C|} \cdot 1 \cdot -1 ,& -x-C > 0\\ 
\end{cases}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\frac{-1}{|x+C|} ,& x > -C  \\ 
\frac{1}{|x+C|} ,& x < -C  \\ 
\end{cases}  \\
\end{align*}
However,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{-\ln|-x-C|} 
    &= \mathrm{e}^{\ln\frac{1}{|-x-C|}}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{|x+C|}  \\
\end{align*}
(and $x \neq -C$ has been implicit throughout both computations).
We see that these are only equal for $x < -C$.  Unless you have some constraint on $x$ that is not present in the Question, the version with the absolute value is not the solution of the differential equation.
